# Calling javascript from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have a c# asp.net 3.5 app
I am trying to open a window from code behind after a certain event. I have this but its not working and there are no errors in firebug

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            if (openCredentialsWindow) {
                if (openCredentialsWindow_ClientId != Guid.Empty) {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openCredentials", string.Format("radopen('Services.aspx?clientId={0}, Window_Services')", openCredentialsWindow_ClientId.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the pre-conditions are true. You need to pass an additional parameter to the `RegisterClientStartupScript` method call to indicate that scriptTags need to be added.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openCredentials", string.Format("radopen('Services.aspx?clientId={0}, Window_Services')", openCredentialsWindow_ClientId.ToString()),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you view the source, after page load, is this code actually rendered into the source?
Can you set a breakpoint at the `this.Page.ClientScript...`-line, to verify that both conditions before it are actually met?