# How to call javascript function from code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling javascript from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828566/calling-javascript-from-code-behind)

I wrote a javascript function on asp.net page. This is that..

> function Alert(){
>             alert('hello');
>        }

I want to call this function from code-behind view. How can I do.

Comment: when do you want to call this function? on click of a button?

Comment: No, I want to call this with form_Load in vb.net code-behind

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Page.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) to setup javascript code to be called on client side page load.