# How to call javascript function from code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wrote a javascript with a asp.net page.

In Asp.net Page

```
<HTML> <HEAD>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function Myfunction(){
          document.getElementId('MyText').value="hi";
      }
      </script>
</HEAD> <BODY>
<input type="text" id="MyText" runat="server" /> </BODY>
```

In Code-behind

```
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  Handles Me.Load
       If Session("My")= "Hi" Then
          I want to call "Myfunction" javascript function
       End If 
 End Sub
```

How can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847819/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Comment: do you really want to call the function from the code-behind, or do you want function to run when the page load? I think it is the last alternative you want.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a way to invoke one or more JavaScript methods from the code behind.
By using Script Manager we can call the methods in sequence. Consider the below code for example.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "UpdateMsg", 
    "$(document).ready(function(){EnableControls();
    alert('Overrides successfully Updated.');
    DisableControls();});", 
true);
```

In this first method EnableControls() is invoked.
Next the alert will be displayed.
Next the DisableControls() method will be invoked.

Answer (score 80):

One way of doing it is to use the `ClientScriptManager`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(), 
    "MyKey", 
    "Myfunction();", 
    true);
```

Comment: Seem like the best way is yours, but what does "MyKey" is ?

Comment: The key is just a unique identifier to help avoid emitting the same script twice. It can be anything.

Comment: the best solution, very simple

Comment: the key shall be a GUID!

Comment: See here if you want the javascript function to execute after the page has loaded https://stackoverflow.com/a/40335689/74585

Answer (score 14):

There is a very simple way in which you can do this. It involves injecting a javascript code to a label control from code behind. here is sample code:

```
<head runat="server"> 
    <title>Calling javascript function from code behind example</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function showDialogue() { 
                alert("this dialogue has been invoked through codebehind."); 
            } 
        </script> 
</head>
```

..........

```
lblJavaScript.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>showDialogue();</script>";
```

Check out the full code here: <s>http://softmate-technologies.com/javascript-from-CodeBehind.htm</s> (dead)
Link from Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20120608053720/http://softmate-technologies.com/javascript-from-CodeBehind.htm

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken :-(

Comment: Loving this solution - it almost feels like cheating.  I suspect it may not be suitable for every scenario but I'm hard pressed to think of a case where it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

***If the order of the execution is not important and you need both some javascript AND some codebehind to be fired on an asp element, heres what you can do.***

What you can take away from my example: 
I have a div covering the ASP control that I want both javascript and codebehind to be ran from. The div's onClick method AND the calendar's OnSelectionChanged event both get fired this way.

In this example, i am using an ASP Calendar control, and im controlling it from both javascript and codebehind:

Front end code:

```
        <div onclick="showHideModal();">
            <asp:Calendar 
                OnSelectionChanged="DatepickerDateChange" ID="DatepickerCalendar" runat="server" 
                BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                Font-Size="8pt" ShowGridLines="true" BackColor="#B8C9E1" BorderColor="#003E51" Width="100%"> 
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#6C5D34"> </OtherMonthDayStyle> 
                <DayHeaderStyle  ForeColor="black" BackColor="#D19000"> </DayHeaderStyle>
                <TitleStyle BackColor="#B8C9E1" ForeColor="Black"> </TitleStyle> 
                <DayStyle BackColor="White"> </DayStyle> 
                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#003E51" Font-Bold="True"> </SelectedDayStyle> 
            </asp:Calendar>
        </div>
```

Codebehind:

```
        protected void DatepickerDateChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toFromPicked.Value == "MainContent_fromDate")
            {
                fromDate.Text = DatepickerCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            }
            else
            {
                toDate.Text = DatepickerCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:run javascript method

Add this line to **the bottom of the page before `</form>` tag**, at least under the `js` function you wrote.

> the reason of doning this is avoid calling your method before your
> browse knowing what is the funcion and finally do nothing.

```
<% Response.Write($"<script>yourfunction('{Config.id}');</script>"); %>
```

`ps:` I've tried all methods up there but nothing worked fine for me. And I figure out this easy and wonder way of calling js method on my own!