# Moving left right with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I am jQuery beginner :) I am trying to move  from left to right but all I did is moving to the right. How to move it back?

```
$(function () {
        $('#box').click(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                "left" : "300px"
        }, 4000);
    });
});
```

Also I have update panel on my page with left right button that do some things in code behind. How to call this left/right function from code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move it back to the left you just append another animate:

```
$(function () {
  $('#box').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
      "left" : "300px"
    }, 4000).animate({
      "left" : "0px"
    }, 4000);
  });
});
```

This is an anonymous function as event handler you can't call, it will only run on the click events on the div. You could move it outside

```
$(function () {
  $('#box').click(boxAnimation);
});

function boxAnimation() {
  $(this).animate({
    "left" : "300px"
  }, 4000).animate({
    "left" : "0px"
  }, 4000);
}
```

and then maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind) will help.

**EDIT:**

I found an [article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/314_Multiple_Ways_to_Call_Javascript_Function_from_CodeBehind_in_ASPNet.aspx) describing how you can call javascript from the code-behind.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. And what about call this move functions from code behind.

Comment: @1110 check the link and see if you can find the answer there. I'm no WebForms developer so I think other people can answer that part better than i can :)

Comment: the `$('#box').click(boxAnimation);` is the answer to your second question. All you need is a named function.