# How to hide custom control after certain time

Tags: asp.net, .net, custom-controls

I have a custom control which displays results of some operations.

It is hidden by default and its made visible on the code-behind of some other class.

Now I want to hide it after a certain amount of time. How do I do it?

**Edit:**

Some answers suggested adding following javascript block at the end of the custom control which is not working if `Visible="false"` is used on the custom control.

But I did not made that clear enough and so accepted that as an answer.
Have to take a look at: [How to call javascript function from code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

The timeout function is correctly called if `Visible="true"` is used.

ASPX:

```
<control id="customControl" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
```

**Solution if `Visible="true"` is used in markup:**

Custom control - ASPX:

```
<div id="body">
    <!-- custom control -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('<%=Me.divBody.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none'; }, 2000);
</script>
```

Custom control - Code-behind:

```
Me.customControl.Visible = True
```

**Solution if `Visible="false"` is used in markup:**
*From start the script block is not rendered and later is not added automatically. So we need to register it.*

Custom control - ASPX:

```
<div id="divBody">
    <!-- custom control -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    window.setTimeout(function(){ alert("test"); });         
</script>
```

Custom control - Code-behind:

```
Me.customControl.Visible = True
Dim hideScript AS String = "window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('" & Me.divBody.ClientID & "').style.display = 'none'; }, 2000);"
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "script", hideScript, True)
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/85960/ASP-NET-Hide-Controls-after-number-of-seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any reference to jQuery in the question, hence vanilla JS solution:
Put this at the end of the User Control file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById("<%=this.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
        }, 5000);

</script>
```

Comment: This is not working, even a simple alert does not gets fired. The element is definetly made visible from code-behind.

Comment: Make sure there are no javascript errors on the page load and check

Comment: I edited my question. The problem is if visible is set to false by default javascript is not called. If it is set to true the element is visible from start and the javascript timeout function is called.

Comment: A check can be added before assigning the setTimeout handler.In either case the solution above should work.. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I reedited my question now with your code suggest and a simple alert example which is not working if `Visible="false"` is used on the custom control.

Comment: Gotcha.. The issue here is if you set the Visible property to false Asp.Net will not render the HTML for that control. Hence the script/code is not rendered to the browser to start with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13613/discussion-between-chandu-and-djmj)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a property on the object which when executed changed the visible property to false if you were outside of a stipulated time frame, so you'd have a visible from and until field and have that generate a boolean when compared to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the javascript `setTimeout` function to execute some code to hide the div which has the user control to hide after a time period

```
<div id="divUserControlContainer">
 //put your user control embed code here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    window.setTimeout(function() {  
         $("#divUserControlContainer").hide();
    }, 2000);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You achieve it by simple JQuery methods:

```
$("#CustomControl").hide(1000);
$("#CustomControl").show();
```