# How do I call javascript function from codebehind with ClientScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call javascript function from code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

I have an empty div that I want to be adding check boxes to if a code behind boolean is true.

Here is the div:

```
<div id="checkboxes" />
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function addCheckboxes() {
            alert("just an alert for now");
        }
```

And here is my code behind where I want to call the "addCheckboxes" function:

```
bool isMovingTask = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["isMovingTask"].ToString());
        if (isMovingTask)
        {
            //call javascript function
        }
```

Comment: I heard something about client script but I had no idea what it is. I just realized after martin sent me the link how it works. However I guessed I could have looked up on msdn....But I wasn't too sure if there was anything else that needed to be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See related answer here: [How to call javascript function from code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Basically you want to make a call to register your client script, there are a few ways to do this in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is called when server execution of code and finished and generated html/script response is sent to browser. You can access public property of code behind in javascript and use it.

Make a public property in code behind and assign value to it in code behind

**Code Behind**

```
public  bool isChecked = true;
```

**Html**

```
    function addCheckboxes() {

       if('<%= isChecked %>' == 'True')
       {
          //Your code here
          alert("just an alert for now");

       }
    }
```