# how to call javascript function from vb.net code?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have written VB.NET code for calling my Javascript function `showDisplay()`.

vb.net code:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "showDisplay();", True)
```

javascript code:

```
function showDisplay(){
alert('success');}
```

but this is not working, can you help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for RegisterStartupScript:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "showDisplay();", True)
```

Depending on where your `showDisplay()` javascript function exists in your code, using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` may not find it.  This is because `RegisterClientScriptBlock` places the javascript at the top of your page, immediately after the viewstate.  Using `RegisterStartupScript` will place the call to `showDisplay()` at the very bottom of your form, so it will be rendered last and your javascript function will have already been rendered and available.

Comment: if showdisplay message have arguments how to send it?

Comment: Depends.  Does the server side have knowledge of the argument values?  If so, put them inline `showDisplay(\"StringValue1\", \"StringValue2\")`.  Are the values only available on the browser?  If so, provide variable names and ensure that the JavaScript contains these variables prior to calling `showDisplay(var1, var2)`.

Comment: What if I have my JavaScript function wrote down under a different file?