# Calling .js file function from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have been trying to call .js file function from code behind but function is not being called.

I have this following html button which needs to be visible from the code behind.

```
   <input id="btnShowMap" type="button" value="Results On Map" onclick = "ShowMap();" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

I have tried following three methods so far and none of them is working.

```
 -ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "VoteJsFunc", "test();")

 -Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "VoteJsFunc", "alert('Sorry.You are not legible to vote')", True)

 -ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "VoteJsFunc", "test();")
```

Here is .js file function

```
function test() {
var hdLat = $('input[id$=hdVendorLat]').val();
    var hdLng = $('input[id$=hdVendorLng]').val();
    if (hdLat != 0 && hdLng != 0) {
        $('#btnShowMap').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#btnShowMap').hide();
    }
 }
```

Here is the pahe html

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSearch" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdVendorLat" runat="server" Value="0" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdVendorLng" runat="server" Value="0" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdVenID" runat="server" Value="" />
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlExport" runat="server" Enabled="true">      
  <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="90px" />                          
  <input id="btnShowMap" type="button" value="Results On Map" onclick   = "ShowMap();" style="visibility: hidden;"  />
</asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/inspector-search.js"></script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: show your html file...at least the head area

Comment: Are you sure, that your .js file is included to the html page. Check similar answer at SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Comment: if this isn't working try to wrap your call in a setTimout js...else will execute before page finish loading and you will not see a thing...

Comment: Are you 100% positive that function is not being called? Even if the function is called it will never show the input because an error on your logic

Comment: I have just added the html on my question

Answer (score 1):

try register script, like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "VoteJsFunc", "test()", True)
```

I checked this locally, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery method `show` works over `display` css property. It is equivalent to call `.css( "display", "block")`.

Since you are using `visibility` property, method `show` has no effect on changing this so it remains hidden. I see 2 options to fix this:

- use `.css( "visibility", "visible")` instead of `.show()`
- replace `style="visibility: hidden;"` by `style="display: none"` on your input markup

Comment: are you serious? this is total unrelated to the question. ps: just noobs are using jQuery instead pure jscript

Comment: @HellBaby: since the code seems to be correct everywhere I assumed this was the best explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invoce the mentioned .js file in html before you call the script from which you are calling the function. If you need more information, please include your HTML code.