# How to call Java Script in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the below function in asp.net

```
function Confirm() {

        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");

        confirm_value.type = "hidden";

        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {

            confirm_value.value = "Yes";

        } else {

            confirm_value.value = "No";

        }

        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);

    }
```

Now, I need to call this function confirm in the code file. 
Note: I have the design in page: *.aspx while I have the code in aspx.cs. 
How can I call it in aspx.cs while I write this function in aspx file.

Comment: When you want to call this function e.g. on some button click or on form load?

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", "<script>Confirm();</script>")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

From code behindC# you can register (java)script block to run on page like following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","Confirm()",true);
```

or with JQuery after pageload:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    Confirm();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input now how to use the values which are there? How can I check if the user inputs yes or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
string myScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"Javascript\" id=\"EventScriptBlock\">\n";
myScript += "$('#DvEmptyPush').show()";
myScript += "</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key1", myScript, false);
```

Comment: try to give proper explanation to your answer than just throwing away only codes

Answer (score 0):

You made a big confusion here. I suggest you to try to understand the client-side programing and server-side programing concepts. Here are some videos (there are with php, but is the same with asp.net) that will help you understand why what you ask here has no sense:

http://www.killerphp.com/videos/serverside_programming_languages/serverside_programming_languages.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcBB2Fp8WNI

https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-php-application/getting-started-with-php/serverside-versus-clientside-2

The javascript code is execuded on the client(browser). 
The aspx.cs/c# code is executed on the server. You use .aspx and .aspx.cs files on the server to write dynamically html, javascript, etc... on the Response. The Response that can contains html, javascript and other stuff gets to the client(browser) where is interpreted(html) or executed(javascript).

That javascript function can be called only on the client, not on the server - on the server you can only write javascript.