# Call Javascript from codebehind asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to get a fancybox to open with a div and a gridview once the gridview has been populated with data.

I can either get the fancybox to open with nothing by calling the fancybox directly, or i can populate the girdview without the showing the fancybox.

this is the code i have that just populates the girdview at the moment as this is where I need to go from.

Any and all help appreicated.

The method

```
 Public Sub GetEmailContacts()

    Session("RoleCode") = 27

    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dtToBind As DataTable = New DataTable()

    dtToBind.Columns.Add("Contact Type", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dtToBind.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dtToBind.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dtToBind.Columns.Add("Email Address", Type.GetType("System.String"))


    dt = GetValues()

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        dtToBind.Rows.Add(dr(0).ToString(), dr(6).ToString(), dr(7).ToString(), dr(9).ToString())
    Next

    For Each dr As DataRow In dtToBind.Rows
        Dim toButtonField = New ButtonField() With {
            .ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
            .Text = "To: ",
            .CommandName = "DoSomething"
        }


        Dim ccbuttonField = New ButtonField() With {
            .ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
            .Text = "Cc: ",
            .CommandName = "DoSomething"
        }

        gvContactList.Columns.Add(toButtonField)
        gvContactList.Columns.Add(ccbuttonField)

        Exit For
    Next

    gvContactList.DataSource = dtToBind
    gvContactList.DataBind()

    bttnTo.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "#emailAddress")

End Sub
```

The LinkButton :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" cssclass="fancybox" ID="bttnTo" OnClick="getEmailContacts"><span style='font-size: 20px; color: darkgreen'><i id="toEmail" class="fa fa-users sameRow margin10"></i></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

this is whats in the JS File too

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    parent: "form:first" // jQuery selector
});
```

});

a standard link

```
<a href="#emailAddresses" class="fancybox"><span style='font-size: 20px; color: darkgreen'><i id="toEmail" class="fa fa-users sameRow margin10"></i></span></a>
```

how would be best to call this function?

Comment: Check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind

Comment: just edited my question, so show my js file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here update your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fancybox = $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        parent: "form:first" // jQuery selector
    });
    if (gridLoaded) {
        fancybox.click();
    }
});
```

You must `gridLoaded` to false on first page load, then when you are done loading the grid set the `gridLoaded` to true.

Comment: the linkButton is calling the getEmailContacts already if you take a look at the code, its the #emailAddresss i need to get to open the div in the fancy box

Comment: the standard `<a href="...">` works to call the fancybox, the linkbutton calls the codebehind, but what i need is to have the linkbutton to call the method, then call the javascript to open the fancybox

Comment: This answer is what you looking for then. It's the JQuery that's your problem. Instead of getEmailContacts(); use $('#getEmailContacts').click();

Comment: can you adjust your answer to show me how you mean then please

Comment: Sorry I mean't $('#emailAddresses').click(), I've updated the answer.

Comment: i need both the method getEmailContacts from my .net code behind to fire and then the fancybox to open,

Comment: Aaah, I think you need to word your question better.  Now that makes more sense. I was trying to piece together the question. I will update with recommendation.

Comment: Do you have a JS function getEmailContacts() that calls your backend GetEmailContacts? Or is that ASP link a direct call to GetEmailContacts on your backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91266/discussion-between-simon-price-and-martin-swanepoel).