# How to change value in array from asp.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays

I am loading the value of string `myvalue` (global string) in array `arr` in javascript by

```
function hello()
{
   alert("hi");
   var arr=[<% myvalue %>];
   alert(arr);
}
```

---

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myvalue="1234";
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "whatiskey", "hello();", true);  
}
```

and updating `myvalue` on `listbox1.item` select and calling method which updates value of `arr`, but javascript `arr` does not load the new value

Answer (score 1):

you have to put double quotes and write it like:

```
var arr=["<%=myvalue %>"];
```

or more better way :

```
var arr= new Array();
arr.push("<%=myvalue %>");
```

Comment: the problem is method is not being called , it is not showing any alert , how to solve it

Comment: have a look on :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind

Answer (score 0):

Register ListBox1 as partial post back element could also be one of the reason.

are you able debug, that `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` is being called.

You need to something like below to stop this from multiple time registered, this can one of the reason not to call hello(). Use F12 to investigate the rendered HTML.

```
// Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, csname2))
    {
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "aNewKey",  "hello();", true);  
    }
```

Comment: The method hello() is not being executed , what is the problem here ?

Comment: is ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged executed, are you sure?