# Unexpected identifier when using registerstartupscript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am fairly new to js and am having trouble when trying to call a js function from my codebehind.

C#:

```
protected void GridView3_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbListOfCountries.Text = GridView3.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "test()", true);   
        }
```

JavaScript:

```
 function test() {
       alert("test");     
    }
```

And the Unexpected Identifier error:

```
//<![CDATA[
test()Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.TabPanel, {"headerTab":$get("__tab_TabContainer1_TabPanel1"),"ownerID":"TabContainer1","wasLoadedOnce":true}, null, {"owner":"TabContainer1"}, $get("TabContainer1_TabPanel1"));
});
```

Any insights?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your script `test()` isn't syntactically correct. Try replacing with `test();`

Comment: I have tried that as well, but then I get the `ReferenceError:test is not defined`

Comment: Well, you do actually need a method called `test()` in one of your script resources or in a `<script>` block in order for it to work. E.g., if you replace `test();` with `alert('boo!');` it should run

Comment: Excellent pick ';` missing

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this in an `UpdatePanel` you may encounter some issues (especially on PostBack). I find this version works best:

```
Control sender = MyUpdatePanel;
string javaScript = "alert('Hello');"; 
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(sender, sender.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), javaScript, true);
```

You'll need a ScriptManager tag on the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MyScriptManager" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I've tried your example and it works for the alert, however, when I try to set `string javascript` to the name of my function, it is no longer firing. Am i missing something?

Comment: Your function maybe out of context, is it at the top of the page or at the bottom? And is it nested in an UpdatePanel? Press F12 on your browser and see the Console for javascript errors this will give you a better indication of that's gone wrong.