# MsgBox doesn't work after deployment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, msgbox

I've deployed my ASP.NET application today. It's a web application (I am using forms, etc.). I was happy with all my functionalities. For example, I had part of the of the code that says

```
if c.results = " " then MsgBox("Error! No record was returned)
```

Then I clear all my text boxes.

That MsgBox was working when I was running my application locally, but now that I've deployed it I get a server run error! I read some similar posts that said MsgBox is not supported with web applications, but all their answers were with JavaScript. I am  not familiar with it, but I don't understand how to put my JavaScript in my Visual Basic class instead of where I am calling the MsgBox- is there a way fixing the above issue with VB.NET code?

Here is the code:

```
Dim results = customer.getCustomerDetails(txtCustomerNumber.Text, txtDOB.Text)

If (results.customerNumber = "") Then
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Customer record not found')</script>")

    txtCustomerNumber.Text = ""
    txtDOB.Text = ""

Else
    ( Do the other stuff)

End if
```

Comment: `MsgBox` is a WINforms function, not a WEBforms one. Use javascript `alert` or a modal popup. You can call client side scripts with `ScriptManager`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you please explain more? How can you in a vb code specify that if results "" then call the JavaScript alert box. I hardly worked with JavaScript and I can't get my head around , also I can't find a document that walk through an example. Thank you

Comment: Basically I am trying to say my functionality is written in vb.net and JavaScript is client side how can I mix both as in vb.net do the above if statement check then replace MsgBox with JavaScript alert?!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client side and server side code.

Comment: msgbox is server side so it can't show up to the client which is only seeing the client side of the asp.net webform, hence use the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>alert('your wanted message');</script>") if you want to access javascript alert from code behind or simply alert in javascript

Comment: @JKOU your answer is the correct one, if you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: ok I will  do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MsgBox is server side so it can't show up to the client which is only seeing the client side of the ASP.NET webform, hence use the following if you want to access a JavaScript alert from code behind or simply alert in JavaScript:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "<script 
language=JavaScript>alert('your wanted message');</script>")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate client code from your server side VB as such:

```
If c.results = " " Then
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Error! No record was returned')</script>")
End If
```

Comment: The respone.write may cause some problems sometimes, instead use the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>alert('your wanted message');</script>")

Comment: What sort of problems might be experienced?

Comment: well for example, one time i was using response.write and it ruined my interface while showing up the popup message, instead try to use the code i set above.

Comment: Fair do's. Never had any issues myself but will bear that in mind

Comment: ok that's great, it depends on your situation, i hope you do not have to face it, just in case something happens, use the code i provided instead

Comment: Response.Write did affect on my interface. The tab disappeared however JKOU code made the date calendar looks messy! Not sure what is the ideal way

Comment: you need to post some more code (perhaps the full method you have this code in) to understand better what may be causing that. We can't see any code for your calendar

Comment: I've added my code. However the calender is Jquery code . in the aspx, I don't think thats an issue coz it was okay before adding Respone code

Comment: I've read the problem with the Calender changing and Font becoming bigger is due to Response.Write messing up with HTML code. So its defintley an issue with that. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?468711-RESOLVED-bigger-font-after-postback

Comment: @Warda you can use ajax control toolkit for the ajax calendar extender, which can be used as a calendar and bind it to a control, or you can show us the jquery code so i can test around

Comment: Please do not recommend using `Response.Write` to run JavaScript in Web Forms. That's not the proper mechanism to do it.