# Calling function in .js file from aspx.cs CodeBehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having a weird issue.

I have this function in a Javascript file which is imported in the header section of the .html:

```
function MyJSFunction(param){
    console.log(param);
}
```

Having this snippet in a button click event (which it works and fires properly):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "MyJSFunction", "MyJSFunction('hello world')", true);
```

I do have the `ScriptManager` correctly imported in the `.aspx` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function from code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848678/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind)