# Javascript method call from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I visited [Calling java script from codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828566/calling-javascript-from-code-behind)  and other questions marked as duplicate by some users. But specific to my problem none of them are helpful.

I have an already built CMS and I need to change one of the module which was built using a user control. I cannot hereby add `runat="server"`attribute to the `form` and `head` tags.

I am having a

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdvResxKeyValue" runat="server" Width="100%"AutoGenerateColumns="False">`</asp:GridView>`
```

and

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvList" ShowLines="True" runat="server" ImageSet="Msdn"  OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvList_SelectedNodeChanged">
                    <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="sfSelectednode" />
                </asp:TreeView>
```

`gdvResxKeyValue` is bind while selection of nodes is made in treeview ie.

```
protected void tvList_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gdvResxKeyValue.DataSource = lstResDef;
    gdvResxKeyValue.DataBind();
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),LocalizationGlobalVariable5", string.Format("edition();"), true);
}
```

At last column of `gdvResxKeyValue` I have an image as

```
<asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgEditResxValue" CssClass="sfEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Administrator/Templates/Default/images/imgedit.png" />
       </ItemTemplate>                            
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and I need a image click handler using javascript using minified version of jquery-1.9.1.js. so have written code as..

```
<script type="text/javascript">


//<![CDATA[
$.Localization = {
    TextAreaID: 0,
    FilePath: "",
    ID: 0,
    GridID: '<%=gdvResxKeyValue.ClientID%>'
};
function edition() {
    $('#'+ $.Localization.GridID).on('click', 'img[class="sfEdit"]', function () {
        var index = $(this).attr("alt");
        $.Localization.ID = index;
        var data = $('#' + $.Localization.GridID + ' textarea[title="' + index + '"]').val();
        $('#txtResxValueEditor').val(data);
        ShowPopUp("editorDiv");
    });
}
</script>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather calling javascript method on clicking the image. On the ready of document I have written following code and finally got my problem solved.

```
  $(document).on('click', "#" + $.Localization.GridID + ' img.sfEdit', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).attr("alt");
    $.Localization.ID = index;
    var data = $('#' + $.Localization.GridID + ' textarea[title="' + index + '"]').val();
    $('#txtResxValueEditor').val(data);
    ShowPopUp("editorDiv");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your grid to div wrapper:

```
<div id="myDiv">
....<asp:GridView ID="gdvResxKeyValue"....
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$('#myDiv .sfEdit').click(function(){
  alert('called');
});
```

EDIT: just noticed you call the startup script registration on every postback (the Change event of your treeview). It's not needed. Simply include your JavaScript file, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myDiv .sfEdit').click(function(){
      var imgId = $(this).attr('id');
      alert('called ' + imgId);
    });
});
```

and keep the gridview in div wrapper as described above.

Comment: I have done as you suggested to wrap the gridview with a div and have code something like $('.sfGridwrapper').find('#' + $.Localization.GridID).on('click','img[class="sfEdit"]', function () { but still its not working.

Comment: when you have a wrapper, you shouldn't need the .find(..gridID..) anymore. Just try this first: $('.sfGridwrapper').on('click','img[class="sfEdit"]', function () {