# Calling a Javascript function from .cs

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have an Update panel where a button and a grid are added as follows:  this._UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(this._BtnSave); this._UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(this._AssignGrid);

On click of this button I am calling a function which resides in a different class AssignedGrid.cs.
    this._AssignedGrid.getSelectedRows();

AssignedGrid.cs inturn calls a javascript function as follows:

```
  public void getSelectedRows()
  {
      this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "GetSelectedItems", "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>GetSelectedItems();</script>");    
  }
```

But this javascript function is never called! Please let me know if I am calling the function the proper way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828566/calling-javascript-from-code-behind

Comment: I even tried an alert as follows, but did not work:  this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "GetSelectedItems", "alert('ok');");

Comment: Does the page use UpdatePanel?

Comment: @ Yuriy Galanter yes it has an UpdatePanel.

Comment: Then see the answer below. Instead of `ClientScript` you need to use `ScriptManager` to call `RegisterStartupScript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScrip(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "GetSelectedItems", "GetSelectedItems();", true);
```

The first parameter of the Script manager expects a page object ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

This is probably a user control, web control, etc and not an actual page object, as such it doesn't work.  The only time this works is if you are in the context of a page, e.g. like a class that inherits from page.

So just send it the page object explicitly.

Once you have that, if it's not getting called, use a browser like Chrome, open the developer tools (f12) and go to the console window and look for javascript errors.  If it was called but wasn't found you should see "GetSelectedItems does not exist" or a similar error.  And that would mean your function is being declared and loaded after the code that calls it was inserted in the dom order by the ScriptManager.

The ScriptManager will insert the code call at the end of the page before the  close tag, so define GetSelectedItems in the  tag or somewhere above it.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to give script tags

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "GetSelectedItems", "GetSelectedItems();", true);
```

Comment: @ chandresh patel..Thanks for the response..But did not work!

Comment: try this this are the only ways ScriptManager.RegisterClientScript(this, GetType(),"GetSelectedItems", "GetSelectedItems();", true);